# Redirect signals from matplotlib Figure to a PyQt4 QMainWindow

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4

I have a PyQt4 Gui which spawns several figures.

Some of the figures have their own mouse click events which I use mpl_conect to interface with.

My PyQt4 Main Window has several actions with shortcuts. I'll use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> as an example. When the `QMainWindow` is focuses everything works as expected.

My question is: How to I get signals like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to fire when I am focused on a Matploblib Figure instead of the `QMainWindow`?

Comment: Can you put up a minimal example?  80% this is a bug in mpl and the widgets are just eating all the key signals and not bouncing them up to the next layer.

Comment: and _how_ are you spawning the additional figures?  Are you doing the embedding your self or using `pyplot`?  If you are using `pyplot`, there are a bunch of things that can go wrong underneath with conflicting mainloops.

Comment: @tcaswell I didn't think this behavior was a bug. It would make sense to not have main window signals fire if they aren't focused. I'm just wondering if there is a way to explicitly bounce the signals. (Perhaps I need to give them a parent object and it will just work?) I am using pyplot.figure to create my figs.

Comment: I think I mis-understood.  I thought you had a figure _in_ a main window.  Using pyplot while embedding is a bad idea (tm).  If you _are_ doing this `fig.canvas.manager.window` should give you a reference to the underlying Qt window.  Also see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2624

Comment: I've been working at this on and off. I tried to catch the key_pressed_event and convert that to a QEvent.KeyPress and send it using app.sendEvent(win, qevent), but I can't seem to make it work. Using the fig.canvas.manager.window, how would I take that underlyuing qt object and redirect keypress signals from it to my main qt window?

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be simple. I feel very silly for overlooking it.

You need to set the shortcutContext of the QAction to Application Shortcut instead of Window Shortcut. As an aside, do disable mpl key press events you can use the following code:

```
      mpl_keypress_shortcuts = [key for key in matplotlib.rcParams.keys() if key.find('keymap') == 0]
      #for key in mpl_keypress_shortcuts:
          #print('%s = %s' % (key, matplotlib.rcParams[key]))
      # Disable mpl shortcuts
      for key in mpl_keypress_shortcuts:
          matplotlib.rcParams[key] = ''
```